# Make Matplotlib Ignore Headings

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, graph

My friend is trying to make a graph using the python import matplotlib and a CSV file I have given her. However, the CSV I've given her includes headings (COUNTRY, COST) so the py program is unable to run properly. The error says "could not convert string to float". Here is her code an example of my file. How can she make the bar chart ignore the first row of the CSV file so the code is able to run 
[image: Sample of the file, including the headings causing problems]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

price = []
countries = []
    
with open ("CpremiumusersEurope.csv","r") as csvfile:
    plot = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in plot:
        price.append(float(row[1]))
        countries.append(str(row[0]))

plt.style.use('grayscale') 
plt.bar( countries, price, label='Europe', color='red')

plt.ylabel('Price in Europe ($)')
plt.title('Cost of spotify premium per country')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the first row like this:

```py
for idx, row in enumerate(plot):
    if idx == 0:
        continue 
    price.append(float(row[1]))
    countries.append(str(row[0]))
```

You could also skip it in this way, which I like less as it's less flexible.

```
for row in plot:
    if row[1] == 'COST':
        continue 
    price.append(float(row[1]))
    countries.append(str(row[0]))
```

Comment: where does this go in the code? beginning or after the CSV has been imported??

Comment: It replaces your `for row in plot:` loop : so after the import.

Comment: I've given this code to my friend and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`csv.reader` returns an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators), so you can call [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on `plot` to advance it to the next row:

```py
with open ("CpremiumusersEurope.csv","r") as csvfile:
    plot = csv.reader(csvfile)
    # Consume the first row from plot
    next(plot)
    # Now loop over the rest of the rows.
    for row in plot:
        price.append(float(row[1]))
        countries.append(str(row[0]))
```